# How to pass parameter in genericgenerator of model to another class (IdGenerator)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to use custom id generator in hibernate. This is my model:

```
@Entity(name="Poli")
@Table(name="POLI")
public class Poli extends DefaultEntityImpl implements Serializable{

    @Id 
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "string-sequence", 
            strategy = "id.rekam.medis.service.generator.IdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                    name = "sequence_name", 
                    value = "pol_seq"),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                    name = "sequence_prefix", 
                    value = "POL-")                
            })
    @GeneratedValue(
            generator = "string-sequence",
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID",nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAMA", length = 10)
    private String nama;   

    //getter setter
}
```

And my IdGenerator Class is :

```
    public class IdGenerator implements  IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(IdGenerator.class);
    private String sequenceName;
    private String sequencePrefix;
    public static final String SEQUENCE_PREFIX = "sequence_prefix";


    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        Connection con = session.connection();
        Long nextValue = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(" SELECT POL_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL ");
            ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                nextValue = rs.getLong("nextVal");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("new id is generated:" + nextValue);

        return "POL-" + nextValue;
    }    

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dlct) throws MappingException {
        sequencePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(SEQUENCE_PREFIX, params,"SEQ_");
    }
}
```

My Goal is, I want that my IdGenerator Class can be used for all Entities/Models. Just need to change the paramters in entity.

My Question: How to catch the parameters in the IdGenerator Class?
I want to get "pol_seq" and "POL-" in IdGenerator Class.

Hot Regard,

Tarmizi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what you've implemented the [Configurable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/Configurable.html) Interface for.

The `configure()` Method has these parameters in the `Properties` parameter. [Look at its JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html?is-external=true), it's basically a HashMap, so just do

```
params.getProperty("sequence_prefix");
```

And maybe you want to turn these names into constants, either public static final Strings, or better yet Enums.